# On the integration over complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Consider the integral:

$I=\int_0^zw dw$

We have $|I|\le \int_0^z|w| dw \le \int_0^z|z| dw \le |z| \int_0^z dw $

The last inequality doesn't make sense for me because $\int_0^z dw$ is not real and I can't see my mistake.

Could you please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, $dw$ is in general not real, so the first inequality is where the problem is. More formally, parameterising the contour by $w=g(t)$ means that $g'(t)$ is not real. One sometimes writes
$$ \left\lvert \int_a^b f(z) \, dz \right\rvert \leq \int_a^b \lvert f(z) \rvert \lvert dz \rvert $$
for the inequality you're looking for, which means that when the contour is parametrised, the integral becomes
$$ \int_a^b \lvert f(z) \rvert \lvert dz \rvert = \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} \lvert f(g(t)) \rvert \lvert g'(t) \rvert \, dt. $$

Comment: Thank you! In that case : do we have $|I|\le \int_0^z|z| |dw| \le |z| \int_0^z |dw| = |z|^2$?

Comment: You have the integral from 0 to z but over **what** path?  With a real valued integral we go straight from 0 to z along the w axis but in the complex plane there are infinitely many paths from one point to another.  That is the "parameterization" Chappers refers to.

Comment: Yes, if the contour is the line segment joining $0$ to $z$. $\int_a^b \lvert dw \rvert$ is the length of the path of integration. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Comment: Thank you for your explanations :)